# How to capture pinch event in a Fennec (Firefox Mobile) add-on?

Tags: firefox, mobile, firefox-addon, fennec

I am developing an add-on for the Fennec (Firefox Mobile).

I want to fire a trigger after the user is doing 2 finger pinch to zoom out and keeps zooming out after the max zoom-out for more than 1 second.

How can I catch that event?